# how to introduce multiplication in shell scripting

Tags: shell-script, awk

My command is:

```
tac some_directory/*.pre | grep -im1 "vdr" | cut -c129-140
```

Output is:

```
1.710577E-03
```

I want the output to be:

```
1.71
```

How can I achieve this in the shell command?

Comment: post a testable input fragment

Comment: USe `tac some_directory/*.pre | grep -im1 "vdr" | cut -c129-132`

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: its exponential of `-3` output will be 0.00171

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **awk**:

As per your expected output:

```
echo 1.710577E-03 | awk '{printf "%.2f\n",a=$1*1000; a}'
1.71
```

Actual roundoff:

```
echo 1.710577E-03 | awk '{printf "%.5f\n",$1}'
0.00171
```

- `%.5` print up to 5 decimals.
- `f` float converter.